# Setting state fo multi step form using React Hooks Helper (link to codesandbox)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to build a registration page using react hook helper.Unable to use SetForm for storing the base64 string generated. Able to retain the state by going next and previous as well.Thank you for your responses.
The link to the project : https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-cherry-yvj90?file=/src/Second.js

MultiStepForm.js

```
import { useForm, useStep } from "react-hooks-helper"

const defaultData = {
    FIRST_NAME: "",
    LAST_NAME: "",
    PHOTO: "",

const steps = [
    { id: 'details' },
    { id: 'photo' },
]
const RegistrationMultiStepForm = () => {

    const [formData, setForm] = useForm(defaultData);
    const props = { formData, setForm, navigation }
    const { step, navigation } = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0
    })
    switch (step.id) {
        case 'details':
            return <Registration_First {...props} />

        case 'photo':
            return <Registration_Second {...props} />

    }
```

Registration_First.js

```
     const Registration_First = ({ formData, setForm, navigation }) => {
     const { FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME } = formData;
       <input
        placeholder='Enter your details'
        type='text'
        name="FIRST_NAME"
        onChange={setForm}
        value={FIRST_NAME} />

     <button onClick={() => navigation.next()}
```

Registration_Second.js (here I am unbale to set the value for photo..). The {result} is the base64 image string which I am trying to add to my state i.e setForm for assigning the value of PHOTO field.

```
configuration same as Registration_First

 const Cropped = () => {

// this does not work which is the correct way 
   setForm((previousState) => {
      previousState.PHOTO = result
      return previousState
   })

//this works...wrong way
   formData.PHOTO = result;
}
```

What i expect": On update of {result} value with the base64 string, i want to call the setForm action and pass the value of {result} to my PHOTO field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the code sandbox I found out what dependency the hook comes from: `react-hooks-helper` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-helper

React Hooks Helper is supposed to be used roughly something like this:

```
const [{ FIRST_NAME, PHOTO }, setValue] = useForm()
...
<input name='FIRST_NAME' value={FIRST_NAME} onChange={setValue} />
```

In your case your using an onCrop event to set the value of the PHOTO to a data url when the user is done with the canvas ui stuff.

```
cosnt Cropped = () => {
  formData.PHOTO = result
}
```

This is incorrect and an anti-pattern. State should be immutable and not be changed directly. That's why the state doesn't show the update untill then next time the state is changed elsewhare. You should use a setter instead so React can update itself.

ANSWER: since were using the react-hook-helpers library we need to pass in the data it expects. We cant pass in a string we have to pass in something that looks like the form onChange argument object.

```
const Cropped = () => {
  setForm({
    target: {
      name: 'PHOTO', // form element
      value: result // the data/url
    }
  })
}
```

Once you do this you should see that the state will update automatically.
You can see what the library code is doing here: https://github.com/revelcw/react-hooks-helper/blob/develop/src/useForm.js

Note: For what its worth they haven't updated the library in 2 years. But it looks like a decent lib with documentation and what not. So that's nice.

Comment: It shows this error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: it worked...by  const Cropped = () => {
        formData.PHOTO = result;
     }

Comment: formData should be immutable so reassigning it without using a setter is an anti pattern. Although it will probably work in some cases it could cause other bugs in the future. We need to figure out why setForm isn't working as expected. Do you have a code pen example?

Comment: Hello friend, here is the link to the url. .https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-cherry-yvj90?file=/src/Second.js

Comment: That's help full. Here's a working version. I dug into the documentation for the dependency `react-hooks-helper`. And found that the function setForm from the useForm tuple is ment to be used inline as the onChange function. So it needs an object that conains the name and value of the form element.   https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-dawn-q6e7z?file=/src/Second.js I'll update my answer.

Comment: hello friends, can you look into this new issue and suggest your codes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63931782/optimize-react-codes-for-time-availabilty-based-on-week-days